# Javascript assigning class scope to local variable ineffective

Tags: javascript, class, accessor, mutators

I first found this idea on this site:

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/01/javascript-dynamically-generating-accessor-and-mutation-methods/

The point is to assign a local variable to the class scope to set dynamic class properties.

In this code I set a local variable _this equal to the class scope. But for some reason, the properties of _this are accessible outside of the class. Why is this? _this is declared a private member when it is created.

```
var MyClass = function( arg )
{
var _this = this;
_this.arg = arg;

// Creates accessor/mutator methods for each private field assigned to _this.
for (var prop in _this)
{
    // Camelcases methods.
    var camel = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.slice(1);

    // Accessor
    _this["get" + camel] = function() {return _this[prop];};

    // Mutator
    _this["set" + camel] = function ( newValue ) {_this[prop] = newValue;};
}
};

var obj = new MyClass("value");
alert(obj.getArg());
```

How come this will run? It will alert "value". This shouldn't be accessible because _this is declared privately. When I wrote this, I did the mutator/accessor assignment wrong; or so I though.

I meant to write this, assigning these methods to the class scope:

```
    // Accessor
    this["get" + camel] = function() {return _this[prop];};

    // Mutator
    this["set" + camel] = function ( newValue ) {_this[prop] = newValue;};
```

But either work. Why is it that _this' private methods are available?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks,
Confused Scripter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `_this` is just a copy of `this`, so both will refer to the newly-created object.  It's the object itself that's available.

In other words, one reference to an object is as good as another. In your code, there are three:

1. `this`, inside the constructor
2. `_this`, also inside the constructor
3. `obj`, which is assigned a reference to the same object as a result of the `new` expression.

In newer JavaScript implementations, it's possible to make properties be hidden, but that hiding applies globally.  JavaScript doesn't have anything like "class scope" that languages like C++ or Java do.

Comment: so when I create _this.property1 I am creating this.property2? Is there any way around this?

Comment: When you create `_this.property1` you're creating a property called "property1" on the object referred to by the variable `_this`. That's the same object that `this` refers to, so yes.  It's possible to create read-only properties of objects, but they're read-only to everything, including methods associated with other properties of the object.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve, I (or somebody) could offer more detailed guidance.

Comment: I apologize. I'm not trying to achieve anything. I was merely confused at this aspect of Javascript. I am not completely satisfied, but you did answer my original question. And my further insatiation is beyond the scope of this question. So thank you!